# fail to access mysql via docker link

Tags: mysql, docker, wildfly

I use two docker containers, one with mysql and another with a wildfly application. It works fine if I start them this way:

```
docker run -d --name db -p 3306:3306 mysql_server 
docker run -d wildfly_server
```

But as port 3306 is normally used in my host, I'd like to use the link feature of docker:

```
docker run -d --name db  mysql_server 
docker run -d --link db  wildfly_server
```

This is supposed to work, but it doesn't: The wildfly now fails to start with

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability.
```

due to ...   (later in the stack) `com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)`

Earlier in the logfile I find a line:

```
INFO  [org.eclipse.persistence.connection] Connected: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/mydb
```

so the mysql connection seems to connect, but not really work afterwards.

What difference could the docker link command make to the mysql connection? To my understanding it should only replace the public 3306 port by a private 3306 port?

And how could I test the jdbc-connection from the wildfly-server independent from wildfly?

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation showed, that this has (almost) nothing to do with docker. With docker --link db the connection to the database seems to slow down, so the initialization of the database takes more than 5 minutes instead of 2-3 minutes, thus wildfly times out.